# Smartface emulator ios 9 gives error

Tags: smartface.io

Although i have downloaded smartface-in-action app from appstore i get following error for simulator:

> Searching for devices
>   Device found: ipod’s iPad
>   Keep calm 
>   You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again.
>   Please refer to Troubleshooting document!

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Smartface in Action on the app store is not supporting Device Emulator feature anymore.

You need to purchase "Individual License" minimum for Device Emulator option.

For more information https://account.smartface.io/License